# How to know if a thread is blocked by Reader.read()?

Tags: java, java-io

In the document of `Reader.read()` it says

> Reads a single character. This method will block until a character is available, an I/O error occurs, or the end of the stream is reached.

When `read()` doesn't get anything from the stream, it will block. However, this kind of "blocking" doesn't turn the thread into `State.BLOCKED` or `State.WAITING` -- the thread is still in `State.RUNNABLE` when `read()` waits for the first character, thus I can't know if the thread is blocked by a `read()`.

So how can I know if `Reader.read()` is blocking in a thread from another thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a stack trace for the Thread and see which method it is running at that point.

Or what I do is set a time when the read starts which is clearer when the read finishes. I have another thread which checks this time and issues a warning when it has been too long.

Comment: I want to make `Reader.read()` throw an IOException.. So what I am trying to do is to start a process that just stay in memory to make `read()` waiting, and then, when everthing is ready, kill that process.

Comment: Waiting for a reader to timeout to assume it has finished is pretty flawed. You would only do this if you had a poor protocol you can't change.  You can trigger an IOException by close()ing the Reader.

Comment: A better approach is to have the protocol send the length or use a terminating strings so you will know when the end is reached.  You want have the reader terminate incorrectly if there is an unexpected delay.

Comment: It's not about protocol. In a method in another class, it starts a process using `ProcessBuilder` and then reads the output of that process; what I can do is to tell it which program it should start. So if I can start my dummy program and kill it at the right time, the `Reader.read` should throw IOException because the stream it is reading from just disappears. -- I just want to make an I/O error occur when the `Reader` is trying to read.

Comment: "I just want to make an I/O error occur when the Reader is trying to read." Its not clear what you are trying to achieve or why you are reading at all if this is what you want.

Comment: Cuz' I want to make the codes in the `catch` block to be executed -- I am doing code coverage.

Comment: As you say, this will happen normally, when the process you run finishes. It not clear to me why you want to do it prematurely.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15164/discussion-between-coolcfan-and-peter-lawrey)

Comment: Reader.read() will return -1 if the stream it is reading 'just disappears'. I am having a hard time detecting the actual purpose here.

Comment: @EJP Since the OP doesn't have a reference to the Reader OR the Thread, monitoring or closing is rather difficult.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I didn't even get that far with it. Why does he need to know what one thread is doing in another thread? What difference can it make to know?

Comment: @EJP I get the impression he want to know when the thread has stopped reading and trigger an IOException when it has. I keep telling him he should assume that he will get an IOException or null or -1 when the end of the stream is reached. I get the impression he is trying to solve some buggy situation which needs more investigation rather than trying to find a workaround esp as he doesn't have references to the objects which allow a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just check with `Reader#ready()` if your read is going to block?

Comment: Cuz' I don't have access to the `Reader` instance.

Answer (score 0):

Just set a read timeout with Socket.setSoTimeout() and catch SocketTimeoutException.